# JQuery Form Submit with validation and Ajax (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am struggling with a javascript script which should validate and submit a form with ajax.
Everything is working fine but for some reason the ajax-part does not. After clicking on submit, it seems to do everything fine, but in the very last second it redirects me to the .php file with the success-message it should send back.

Somewhat hard to explain. The form is sent correctly but it does not stay on the form.html page as expected.

I am far from a pro with javascript. Could you guys just have a look at my script and tell me if I have done anything wrong?

```js
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
                if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "email/personal-contact.php",
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            // type of the message: success / danger + message
                            var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                            var messageText = data.message;

                            // Bootstrap alert box HTML
                            var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                            if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                                // inject the alert to .messages div
                                $('#returnmessage').html(alertBox);
                                
                                // empty the form
                                $('#personalcontactform')[0].reset();
                                $('#personalcontactform').removeClass('was-validated');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks a lot.

**Edit**:
Thanks to Chris G with his comment. Adding `event.preventDefault();` after `if (form.checkValidity() === true) {` actually was the soltion.

Comment: You should always call `event.preventDefault();`, regardless of the form being valid or not. With your current code, the form is also being submitted the regular way, which gives the result you describe.

Comment: this was the solution. thanks alot.